# Meaning of Bison Output file

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am writing Java Parser in Bison and Flex. I have written the grammar rules and there are some conflicts in them (378 rr conflicts). I am resolving them but I am having hard time understanding the semantics of the bison output file (parser.output) which is created when we add -d or -v flag in the command. Below is the screenshot of the section of output file.

[image]

Here, the state 170 is reached when we read `ABSTRACT_KEYWORD` terminal. In each state, we get many shift and reduce actions. I understood shift action as follows. Say we get STATIC_KEYWORD as the next input symbol, then we shift to state 60. However, I couldn't understand the reduce actions. Doesn't reduce action mean that we reduce the given terminal to some other non-terminal. For. eg. X -> y, here y is reduced to X. Then why in the output file, the reduce actions are written as `PRIVATE_KEYWRODS   reduce using rule 420`. What does the terminal `PRIVATE_KEYWRODS` has to do with the reduce action of `ABSTRACT_KEYWORD`. If also possible can you provide any material where I can find specification of bison output file since I can't find one on google.

EDIT : Okay, I understood this I think. Is it just like when we create LALR or LR(1) parsing table, we see if the production of form `[A -> X ., a]` is present in the given state and if it is present, then we add reduce action to in parsing table M for entry M[A,a]. I understood this part and I think this is why there are terminals and their reduce actions.
But, what do these terminals (say `PRIVATE_KEYWORDS`) and reduce action mean intuitively. Does it mean this : If next terminal is `PRIVATE_KEYWORDS` then reduce the given terminal `ABSTRACT_KEYWORDS`.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically just showing you the 'action' lookup table for the state -- when in that state, for each possible lookahead token, there is an action to do (shift the token and go to another state, or reduce a rule).

In this case there are multiple actions on some lookaheads -- these are the reduce/reduce conflicts that have been reported.  Bison resolves those conflicts by removing some actions -- the ones in `[`...`]`.  So when the lookahead is `ABSTRACT_KEYWORD` it will reduce rule 420 (and not rule 488)